# error: C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition

Tags: c++, templates

I get the error in the title on two of my templates.  Both have similar declarations and definitions as follows:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2> void setVideoCodecOption(T1 AVCodecContext::*option, T2 (CR2CVideoCodecSettings::*f)() const);

template <typename T1, typename T2>
void EncoderPrivate::setVideoCodecOption(T1 AVCodecContext::*option, (CR2CVideoCodecSettings::*f)() const)
{
    T2 value = (m_videoSettings.*f)();
    if (value != -1) {
        m_videoCodecContext->*option = (m_videoSettings.*f)();
    }
}
```

I don't understand why I am getting this error on these.  Anyone have and idea?

Thanks,
Bear

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing the return type of the function parameter of the second function.

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
void EncoderPrivate::setVideoCodecOption(T1 AVCodecContext::*option, (CR2CVideoCodecSettings::*f)() const)
```

Should be

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
void EncoderPrivate::setVideoCodecOption(T1 AVCodecContext::*option, T2 (CR2CVideoCodecSettings::*f)() const)
                                                                     ^^^added return type
```